# How to rename a site in Sharepoint 2010..?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sitecollection

I want to know how to rename the url in sharepoint site.
For example, my existing site url is

http://example.com/sites/Test/Lists

I want to change it to

http://example.com/sites/Issue/Lists

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new link and forget about the old one would be rather easy....

OR

Once you've created a site the URL you originally specified can't be changed.  The only way I know of to rename a site is to use STSADM and do an export of the site and then import it with the new name.  The subsites would need to be moved underneath the new site which could be done through Manage Content and Structure if you are using MOSS w/ publishing enabled

@From

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/dbbe2a2e-df60-45d1-951d-07fd8dbacdda

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a bit late in the day for this, but:

1) Go to the sub-site
2) Site Actions > Site Settings > Title, Description, and Icon
3) In the Web Site Address section, change the "URL Name:" field to whatever URL extension you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

​Once you've created a site the URL you originally specified can't be changed.  The only way I know of to rename a site is to use STSADM and do an export of the site and then import it with the new name.